# How can I convert this console mongodb query to a C# mongo driver v2 one?

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, aggregation-framework

I want to create a mongodb C# driver 2 query that has the almost same result as the following mongo cli command:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([{$group: { _id: null , "ids" : {$push: {$toString: "$_id"} } } }])
```

The output that I'm looking for is:

```
{ 
    "ids" : 
    [ 
        "5cde5520f838ba2b580852ca", 
        "5d3f012c555aef66082917b0", 
        "5d527092555aef4f28fee38b", 
        "5d52712f555aef4f28fee38c", 
        "5d52719e555aef4f28fee38d" 
    ] 
}
```

I have get this far using the Mongo's drivers overload of Linq functions

```
myCollection
    .AsQueryable()
    .Where(tm => tm.status == mysatus)
    .Select(tm => tm.id)
```

How to create a query that will be resolved on server side and not on client side?

It is not mandatory to use aggregation framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find all the `_id`s and return them in a list like this:

```
public static List<string> GetIds()
{
    var context = new MyContext();
    var builder = Builders<MyCollection>.Filter;
    var filter = builder.Empty;
    var ids = context.MyCollection.Find(filter).Project(x => x.Id.ToString()).ToList();
    return ids;
}
```